# How to select the nth child of each subsequent sibling

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="upload_row_0">
    <tr id="upload_row_1">
    <tr id="upload_row_2">
        <td>
            <select name="task_exec_platform">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="task_exec_config_2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="task_exec_2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="deleteTaskExecRow("#upload_row_2")">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Each row expands and includes similar `<td>` elements, but I am just showing a snippet for brevity's sake. The id `"upload_row_0"` is stored in a variable, `obj`.

I want to select the 2nd child of each subsequent sibling row. In other words, I want to change the name `"task_exec_config_2"` for rows 1 and 2. I am able to capture all the subsequent rows using `nextAll()`, but I am unsure how to select the 2nd child for each of those elements. My current attempt is

```
$(obj).nextAll().$(":nth-child(2)").children().attr("name", "new_name");
```

but I know that this isn't right.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you rely on exactly that DOM structure?

Comment: Yes. The structure will necessarily be exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you just want to move nth-child into next all

```
$(obj).nextAll(':nth-child(2)').attr("name", "new_name");
```

Update
Going off you're original one, i see what youre trying to do.

```
$(obj).nextAll().$(":nth-child(2)").attr("name", "new_name");
```

you need to replace the `$.(...)` after nextAll with `find`, and select the child input

```
$(obj).nextAll().find(":nth-child(2) input").attr("name", "new_name");
```

made a fiddle to visually see what you're selecting:
https://jsfiddle.net/9oqj3z78/2/

Answer (score 3):

Change your second '$' to 'find'

```
$(obj).nextAll().$(":nth-child(2)").attr("name", "new_name");
```

to

```
$(obj).nextAll().find(":nth-child(2)").children().attr("name", "new_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#"+obj)
     .parent('tbody')
         .find('tr')
             .find('td:nth-child(2)')
                 .find('input')
                     .attr('name','new_name');
```

Comment: Ah, I thought that's exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I came up with myself. `eq()` will get a specific child, and then I also needed to select the `<input>` tag in order to change the name appropriately. I just made a mistake in the question by forgetting that `name` was on `<input>` and not `<td>`.

```
$(obj).nextAll().children().eq(1).children("input").attr("name", "new_name");
```